# How to bind Foreign Key? How to create Model objects with foreign key in controller class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following table relationships:

```
ProfileMeta 1 ----- 0...1 ProfileDetail
```

I'm getting a run-time error, after I click on submit on the `Profile/Create` page

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'ContosoUniversity1.dbo.ProfileMeta'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I've properly referenced ProfileMeta as a ForeignKey in Models/ProfileDetail.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    //ProfileMeta is Principal Class
    //ProfileDetail is Dependent Class
    public class ProfileDetail
    {

        //classNameID or ID is interpreted by EF as PK.
        public int ID { get; set; }

        //ForeignKey("<Navigation Property Name>")
        [Key, ForeignKey("ProfileMeta")] 
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ProfileMetaID {get; set;}
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        //Optional Details
        public string HighSchool { get; set; }
        public string UndergraduateSchool { get; set; }
        public string GraduateSchool { get; set; }

        public virtual ProfileMeta ProfileMeta { get; set; }


    }

}
```

Models/ProfileMeta.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    //ProfileMeta is Principal
    //ProfileDetail is Dependent
    public class ProfileMeta
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        public virtual ProfileDetail ProfileDetail {get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<MessageDetail> MessageDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ConversationMeta> ConversationMetas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For a functional signup/register page, I have created a Model: "Register", that references ProfileMeta and ProfileDetail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Register
    {
        public ProfileMeta ProfileMeta_ { get; set; }
        public ProfileDetail ProfileDetail_ { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Views/Profile/Create.cshtml:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Register
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileMeta_.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileMeta_.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileMeta_.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileMeta_.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileMeta_.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileMeta_.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.HighSchool, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.HighSchool, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.HighSchool, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.UndergraduateSchool, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.UndergraduateSchool, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.UndergraduateSchool, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.GraduateSchool, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.GraduateSchool, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail_.GraduateSchool, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

ProfileController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Register register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Add 1 ProfileMeta row and 1 linked ProfileDetail row
            ProfileMeta profileMeta = new ProfileMeta();

            profileMeta.Username = register.ProfileMeta_.Username;
            profileMeta.password = register.ProfileMeta_.password;

            ProfileDetail profileDetail = new ProfileDetail();
            //profileDetail.ID = register.ProfileDetail_.ID;

            //How to assign FK below?
            profileDetail.ProfileMetaID = register.ProfileDetail_.ID;
            profileDetail.UserName = register.ProfileDetail_.UserName;
            profileDetail.Age = register.ProfileDetail_.Age;
            profileDetail.Location = register.ProfileDetail_.Location;
            profileDetail.ProfileMeta = profileMeta;
            //profileDetail.UserName = register.ProfileDetail_.UserName;
            //profileDetail.Age = register.ProfileDetail_.Age;
            //profileDetail.Location = register.ProfileDetail_.Location;


            profileMeta.ProfileDetail = profileDetail;               

            db.ProfileMetas.Add(profileMeta);
            db.ProfileDetails.Add(profileDetail);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(register);
    }
```

Why can't I add a row of ProfileMeta and a corresponding row of ProfileDetail? I thought the database is automatically generating Primary Key (or ID)'s.

Is it necessary to explicitly set the Navigation Properties for a given Model object in the controller?
Also, do I need to explicitly set the Foreign Key: "ProfileMetaID" in the ProfileDetail object I had created?

Comment: Are you getting errors, or just nothing happening?

Comment: "Server Error in '/' Application" when I run my MVC project and submit my form on Profile/Create

Comment: What is the actual error? You have to turn on debugging so you can view the full message. stacktrace + exception message

Comment: just comment this line, profileDetail.ProfileMetaID = register.ProfileDetail_.ID;, it might work.

Comment: Error with Stack Trace: http://pastebin.com/AssVM3cE

Comment: ProfileMeta 1 ----- 0...1 ProfileDetail   by this you mean One-to-Many so a profileDetail can have multiple ProfileMeta?

Comment: No. there is a foreign key constraint of ProfileMetaID in ProfileDetail, that is a given ProfileDetail row can point to 1 and only ProfileMeta row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, I would like to suggest to use EF code conventions instead of explicitly defining the relationships in EF (Your declaration is correct , it's just a personal preference for me and i think it's cleaner).

So instead of this:

```
    //ForeignKey("<Navigation Property Name>")
    [Key, ForeignKey("ProfileMeta")] 
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ProfileMetaID {get; set;}
    public virtual ProfileMeta ProfileMeta { get; set; }
```

You can do:

```
 public int ProfileMetaID { get; set; }
 public virtual ProfileMeta profileMeta { get; set; }
```

`EF` will create the `FK` automatically for you in the DB.

As for your question , I highly recommend that you use ViewModel and include all the attributes you want work with. but if you want to use your existing models , You can use `ProfileMeta`  as your base model and bind the values of `ProfileDetail` using `model.profileDetail.Age`

here's an example:

**Your models (Short version)**

```
public class ProfileDetail
    {

        [Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int ProfileMetaID { get; set; }
        public virtual ProfileMeta profileMeta { get; set; }

    }
    public class ProfileMeta
    {

[Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public virtual ProfileDetail profileDetail {get; set;}
        }
```

Your controller:
(No need to explicitly set the values of your attributes since the relationship and `EF` will take care of it.)

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new ProfileMeta());
        }
     [HttpPost]

     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
         public ActionResult Create(Register register)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {            
                    db.ProfileMetas.Add(profileMeta);
                    db.ProfileDetails.Add(profileDetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                 }
           }
```

**In your View (Just a snapshot)**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.profileDetail.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.profileDetail.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.profileDetail.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And finally here's a fiddle to illustrate the whole concept : https://dotnetfiddle.net/N0prMA

In the fiddle you will see that if you provide an age it will submit it back and display it in the page.