# How to re-add tables based on models defined in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

For some reason, all of my important tables have disappeared from the Database. I've deleted all of my migrations.cs files. Then, I executed a "Add-Migration Initial" and an "Update-Database", but received the following errors:

```
update-database -verbose
Using StartUp project 'DatingSiteInitial'.
Using NuGet project 'DatingSiteInitial'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'ContosoUniversity1' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201504191608070_test].
Applying explicit migration: 201504191608070_test.
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.ProfileMeta_dbo.ProfileDetail_ID]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileMeta] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProfileMeta_dbo.ProfileDetail_ID]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.ProfileMetaConversationMeta_dbo.ProfileMeta_ProfileMeta_ID]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileMetaConversationMeta] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProfileMetaConversationMeta_dbo.ProfileMeta_ProfileMeta_ID]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.ProfileMetaMessageDetail_dbo.ProfileMeta_ProfileMeta_ID]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileMetaMessageDetail] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProfileMetaMessageDetail_dbo.ProfileMeta_ProfileMeta_ID]
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_ID' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[ProfileMeta]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[ProfileMeta]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileMeta] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ProfileMeta]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "dbo.ProfileMeta" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:6efc46ea-dc76-45f9-b275-bb27809b50eb
Cannot find the object "dbo.ProfileMeta" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

How do I simply automatically re-add the tables, based on the defined models first, before applying any foreign key restraints, etc...?

Comment: What are you using? Are you using an ORM?

Comment: Yes, using Entity Framework

Comment: did you have content in your database? or it's not important and all you need is to recreate your tables

Comment: Just need to recreate my tables. I know I manually add CreateTable() in my Migration file, but I'd like to have an automatic way to do so based on the files defined in Models/ if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow these instructions:

1. Delete existing migrations from Migrations_History table.
2. Delete existing migrations from the Migrations Folder.
3. Run `add-migration Reset`. This will create a migration in your
   Migration folder that includes creating the tables (but it will not
   run it so it will not error out.)
4. Now run `update-database`. It will apply the Migration and create a
   snapshot row in MigrationHistory.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at another question I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710434/asp-net-mvc-how-to-bind-foreign-key-how-to-create-model-objects-with-foreign-ke?noredirect=1

Comment: @jerryh91 No Problem, i can help you with it. i just asked you a question there.